# ArcGIS for Server 10.1 (including ArcSDE) and SQL Server 2012 problem with Create Enterprise-Geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

i have the following server system:

-Windows Server 2008R2
-SQL Server 2008 (SDE10 Enterprise Geodatabaees) and SQL Server 2012 on the the same machine
-ArcSDE Application Server 10

First - Is that right, that i do not need to install the ArcSDE 10.1 for Microsoft SQL Server because we use direct connect on the client ?

Now i want to create with ArcGIS 10.1 a new ArcSDE 10.1 Enterprise Geodatabase on SQL Server 2012 with the "create enterprise geodatabase" tool. But i get an error messagge: Unknown errorNo extended error. I look at the sdedc_SQL Server.log:

DB_instance_open() db_connect error: -1
CAN'T OPEN INSTANCE: sde:sqlserver.
Spatial Engine Connection Failed (-51).
Cannot Get Access to Instance sde:sqlserver

Comment: Do you have the Database permissions to create Enterprise Geodatabase on SQL Server 2012 ?

Comment: +1 may be useful for you http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=2290&t=297754 and http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002q000000rm000000

Comment: Yes i have the permisson to create the database.

Comment: When using the create enterprise geodatabase tool, are you specifying the server name, or are you using the 10.0 direct connect syntax (sde:sqlserver:servername)?  You should only be specifying the server name.

Answer (score 2):

SQL-Server 2012 support was [introduced at ArcGIS 10.1 SP1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.1/index.html#//015100000070000000).  You must also have the required SQL-Server 2012 client library install (and its dependent .Net Framework 4.x components) on the ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 client.

Discussion on the "need to install ArcSDE" is more of a philosophical issue (vice  technical), but you can read more about it in the [Esri Forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/57375-Why-would-I-install-ArcSDE-with-10.1).